# Changing display name of pipeline job via rest call to batch endpoint in Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed a pipeline to a batch endpoint in Azure Machine Learning. When I call the REST Api to create a job run a generic job display name is created automatically. How can I modify the job name in the REST call? There seems to be no documentation on it.

I tried to specify "name": ""
And "display_name" and "job_name" but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-batch-endpoints-jobs?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=rest#configure-experiment-name) you can configure the `experimentName`
under `properties`.

Example Json body.

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "InputData": {
           "heart_dataset": {
               "JobInputType" : "UriFolder",
               "Uri": "https://azuremlexampledata.blob.core.windows.net/data/heart-disease-uci/data"
           }
        },
        "properties":
        {
            "experimentName": "my-batch-job-experiment"
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** : This is only valid for pipeline component deployments.

Comment: Hey JayashankarGS! Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not answer my question because I want to change the job display name not the experiment name.

Comment: You deployed using pipeline component right?

Comment: Try giving `jobName` in properties instead of experiment name.